# Piecewise based on the length of the list

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

I want to create a piecewise function that depends on the length of the list.
Let's say I have a list, and a corresponding piecewise function:

```
list1={a,b,c}
pFun=Piecewise[{{{1, x}, x <= list1[[1]]}, {{2, x}, list1[[2]] < x <= list1[[3]]}}, {3, x}]
```

now say if I change the length of the list to 4,

```
list1={a,b,c,d}
```

Is there any possible way to automate the Piecewise function, such that  `list1[[3]] < x <= list1[[4]]` is added based on the length of the list `list1`? The length of `list1` keeps changing and I can't edit `pFun` everytime. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify. (1) The piecewise function never depends on the last value of `list1` in any way. (2) The gap between list1[[1]] and list1[[2]] isn't explicitly covered by the conditions. Correct?

Comment: that's my bad, the list should be {a,b,c} and the last conditional is True or x>=c, either is fine. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't replicate your example, but I'm not sure how to interpret your example. I would probably do something like the following (modify to suit).

```
(* A function to create the condition parts *)
ToConditions[list_, sym_] := Append[(#1 < sym <= #2) & @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1], True];
ToConditions[Range@4, x]
(* gives {1<x<=2,2<x<=3,3<x<=4,True} *)

(* A function to create the value parts *)
ToValues[list_, sym_] := {#, sym} & /@ list;
ToValues[Range@4, x]
(* gives {{1,x},{2,x},{3,x},{4,x}} *)
```

Put it together:

```
Piecewise@Thread[{ToValues[Range@4, x], ToConditions[Range@4, x]}]
```

gives:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the first conditional would be `x<=1`.

Comment: I think I got the answer by tweaking your code a little bit. `ToConditions[list_, sym_] := 
  Flatten[{sym >= list[[1]], (#1 < sym <= #2) & @@@ 
     Partition[list[[2 ;;]], 2, 1], True}];`. This will do it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html).

```
pw[lst_List, sym_Symbol] :=
 Piecewise[
  MapIndexed[
   {v, i} |-> {{First@i, sym}, sym <= v}
   , lst
   ]
  , Null
  ]
```

Then

```
pw[{a, b, c}, x]
```

> [image]

and

```
pw[{a, b, c, h}, y]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Edmund, but the conditionals are  `y<=a`, `a<y<=b`,`b<y<=c` and so on...

Comment: @Rupesh For your constraints you do not need to specify the lower bound as piecewise evaluates each condition in order and stops when a. condition is met. The constraints I have implemented are mathematically equivalent.